# Keep http session alive whilst use is on page

Tags: java, jetty, httpsession

If call `HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval()` with `3600` - meaning an hour and have an AJAX script that hits my sever every 10 minutes, will that be sufficient?

I can't seem to find a reason way to see what sessions are expiring and why, otherwise I would have tested this myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide this entry in web.xml. This will keep the web session alive for 1 hr.

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: I take it that this will keep the session alive for a hour since the last request?

Comment: Yes..This is the session idle timeout. The session will live for the time specified even if you keep the page idle.